# Как заменить строку целиком в StringBuffer?

Tags: java

Есть StringBuffer с текстом

```
persist.ril.rssi.enable.param6=2
persist.ril.version.id=2.7.5
persist.baudrate.rssi.=2566
```

И надобно, скажем, заменить вторую строку на

```
persist.ril.version.id=3,3,3
```

Как это сделать по простому? Пробовал через replaсe, но получается коряво, через delete надо будет определять позицию строки, в общем запутался.

Comment: Вы не пробовали в Google ввести "заменить текст в StringBuffer" ?

Comment: товарищ reinraus, по своей специфике я программист 1С и Delphi, яву начал изучать недавно, многое еще непонятно если от вашего минуса вам стало легче, я рад за вас

Comment: @baralgin1003,  заголовок Вашего вопроса на 90% соответствует запросу к поиску. Минус за Вашу лень, не за вопрос.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

если вы StringBuffer формируете во время считывания из файла или подготовке к записи, тогда лучше всего воспользоватся стандартными средствами, как порекомендовал [[@nk32](/users/5589/nk32)](/users/5589/nk32).

если этот вариант вам не подходит всегда можно использовать методы стрингбуфера или regexp. в обеих случаях не так все сложно ведь каждая строка имеет вид:

```
<key name>=<value>\n
```

где key name и value это имя параметра и его значение. а `'\n'` - символ конца строки. пользуясь этим очень легко обрабатывать данные построчно. например с помощью StringTokanizer, в качестве разделителя указать символ конца строки.

Comment: спасибо, буду пробовать, плюсануть к сожалению не получится, очков маловато(

Comment: Плюсанул по просьбе @baralgin1003. 

Вот интересно, не знал, оказывается сейчас участник с малыми очками плюсовать ответившего не может ? Странное решение.

Comment: спасибо) если можно еще второго участника плюсаните) говорят что оценивать ответы можно, если 15 очков есть, у меня только 9((

Comment: Сами теперь.

Answer (score 2):

Скидывайте буфер в строку и пишите регулярку: replaceAll, replaceFirst. Либо если у вас весь файл key-value pair, как этот кусок, можете сразу забирать его в [Properies](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.util/props.html) и менять значение по ключу.

Comment: вот про  Properies я и не знал... наверно вся ява намного проще, чем мне кажется